# Why Facebook like button (use iframe) not showing when URL is a fan page's post

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

May I ask why when Facebook like button href is a fan page, it's working perfectly.

[image]

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FOscarPet.tw%2F%3Ffref%3Dts&width=450&layout=standard&action=like&show_faces=false&share=true&height=35&appId=PleaseChange2ARealAppId" width="450" height="35" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

But when `href` change to a fan page's "post", the like button not showing any more.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FOscarPet.tw%2Fposts%2F1076964629016757&width=0&layout=standard&action=like&show_faces=false&share=true&height=35&appId=PleaseChange2ARealAppId" width="450" height="35" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Pick the URL of a website or Facebook Page...

It is not possible to use the Like Button for a specific Post on a Facebook Page, you can only use the Page itself - or an external URL.

Comment: Luschn, Thank you very much. I do appreciate your answer. At least let me know Like Button is not working for a specific Post. I will try to find another way, maybe Facebook like API.

Comment: that is exactly what i wrote in my answer, you can´t use it for a specific post.

Comment: Luschn, Thank you. I got the right information from your answer. Thank you very much.